# Facet blocks called on wrong pages

Tags: 7, search

**Problem**

I have a two faceted searches on my site. They both use the database search module. The facets are set-up to only display on the relevant search pages.

(I've limited my paths with the block interface.)

But I just ran :

```
function mymodule_block_view_alter(&$data, $block) {
  dpm($block);
}
```

And I get 9 search facet blocks information appearing on all my non-search pages. (although you can't see them.)

What could I have set-up which means the facets are called on all pages and ignore the block paths?

**My Set-Up**

I have two faceted search pages, one with 9 facets and one with 11.

The 9 facet search is a user search. The 11 facet search is a node search.

I'm using the Database Search and Search API modules.

Comment: I think that is desired behaviour for that function, read more here https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_alter/7

Comment: @DanielHarper I did wonder, but I don't get information for all of the facets, or even all of the blocks. It would also seem weird that Drupal would perform unnecessary queries for block information which isn't going to be used.

Comment: Are some of the facets conditional? if this is the case then I think the facets module removes them before they are available to hook_block_view_alter() that could explain that.

Comment: @DanielHarper Hmm I've not come across that. Do you know where the option for conditional facets is?  I can't seem to find any references to it. (one search is for users, the other nodes if that helps)

Comment: Sorry I have my terminology mixed up it's facet dependencies and you can view them by clicking on the top right hand corner of the block in the same place you would find "configure facet display"

Comment: @DanielHarper Cheers! So i found them but they're disabled for all my facets and enabling any of them removes the facet completely. It does sound like the right thing, but it's not working at all.

Comment: so what is the problem, it's not that clear from the description. The facets just don't show up at all on any page?

Comment: @DanielHarper Sorry about that. So the problem is the facet block information is being called at all of my pages, not just the search ones. Nothing appears but when you run the code in my post it shows they're being called. The explanation on facet dependencies make's it sound like that's the expected result and implies enabling it should remove it, however I found it had no effect.

Comment: I think you may be better posting this question here, https://drupal.org/project/facetapi for a full explanation

Comment: @DanielHarper Yeah I think you might be right. Thanks for sticking with it though!